# Chrome Extension: access page's HTML5 localStorage from content_script

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to access a page's `localStorage` variable from content_script, similar to how a page's `cookies` can be accessed from content_script.

I have no issues accessing a page's cookies from content_script.

However, `localStorage.getItem("showDash")` and `localStorage.setItem("showDash", "value")` don't work in content script. 
The browser doesn't seem to recognize it and throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Why does `localStorage` not work in content_scripts?
Any ways I could work around this?

part of manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["https://cms.mmu.edu.my/*"],
    "js":         ["angular.min.js", "jquery.min.js", "page_handler.js"]
  }]
```

part of page_handler.js:

```
  if (! localStorage.getItem("DashIsOn"))
     localStorage.setItem("DashIsOn", "true");
```

Comment: I am able to access and get localStorage with a content script, suggests to me your error may be elsewhere. Can you post the surrounding code?

Comment: @Alex I second Alex. There should be no issue and I do it myself without a problem.

Comment: this is weird. 
The moment I place this line, 'localStorage.setItem("DashIsOn", "true");' , it gives me the error.
The line is placed in the body of the js file.

Comment: Look at my answer, try to run that code.. it shouldn't fail.

Comment: Still works, your problem is elsewhere... we can't do anything until you provide us the FULL code.

Comment: zip file of manifest.json + page_handler.js
dropbox download:
[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94332063/code.7z)

Answer (score 2):

The `localStorage` is accessible in content scripts, and you can easily test it. Open a tab on *stackoverflow.com* (like this one with your question), keep it active, and run the following code in your background page script/console:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {code: 'alert(localStorage.getItem("se:fkey"));'});
});
```

**NOTE**: since January 2021, use [Manifest V3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/) with [`chrome.scripting.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript) instead of `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`.

You'll see that the alert will come up showing your Stack Exchange key. Therefore your problem must be in another part of the code, or, maybe, yuo're using `localStorage.getItem()` somewhere else than in a content script. **I suggest you to add more code to your question, like the `manifest.json` file and the full `content.js` script.**

Comment: My chrome extension uses `localStorage` without any issues inside a content script, there's no need to create script tags.

Comment: @OmriAharon the OP wants to access **the page's localStorage**, and not the content script's localStorage. Thus, he'll need to inject a script tag.

Comment: The content script is injected to that page, therefore it has access to the page's localStorage, which is unique by domain/subdomain, not javascript files.

Comment: @OmriAharon oh god, I did totally forget that, corrected my answer.

Comment: I have included some codes. the page_handler.js file is really long, over 1k lines.

Comment: The error is in another part of the code! Look at the console log of the error, you will see that in the right side of the line is shown the line and the column number, click them and you'll see where is that error coming from, because it's not coming from localStorage, this is sure.

Comment: Screen grab of the error:
[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94332063/dropbox.png)

Comment: @JoeyCheng "uncomment this line and shit happens" LMAO ahahah. By the way, **I can't see what's the sorcery behind this error...** The only thing I can think of is that, if you want, you can upload the extension .zip file to some site and share it with me so I can debug it personally... otherwise I don't see a concrete solution.

Comment: here's the zip of the extension: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/94332063/CR.7z)

Comment: by the way, I've implemented your hidden bridge method to work around the issue. Thanks. :)